# Expression Evaluation In Haskell: Fixing the type of a sub-expression causes parent expression to be evaluated to different degrees

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation, weak-head-normal-form

I am not able to explain the following behavior:

```
Prelude> let x = 1 + 2
Prelude> let y = (x,x)
Prelude> :sprint y
Prelude> y = _
```

Now when I specify a type for x:

```
Prelude> let x = 1 + 2 ::Int
Prelude> let y = (x,x)
Prelude> :sprint y
Prelude> y = (_,_)
```

Why does the specification of x's type force y to its [weak head normal form (WHNF)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6872898/haskell-what-is-weak-head-normal-form)?

I accidentally discovered this behavior while reading [Simon Marlow's Parallel and Concurrent Programming In Haskell](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1230000000929/ch02.html#sec_par-eval-whnf).

Comment: See also [sprint for polymorphic values](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21518584/791604), though I find it puzzling that `y`'s tuple constructor is visible here even in the monomorphic case, so perhaps it is not a duplicate.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's an informed guess. In your first example,

```
x :: Num a => a
```

So

```
y :: Num a => (a, a)
```

In GHC core, this `y` is a *function* that takes a `Num` dictionary and gives a pair. If you were to *evaluate* `y`, then GHCi would default it for you and apply the `Integer` dictionary. But from what you've shown, it seems likely that doesn't happen with `sprint`. Thus you don't yet have a pair; you have a function that produces one.

When you specialize to `Int`, the dictionary is applied to `x`, so you get

```
x :: Int
y :: (Int, Int)
```

Instead of a function from a dictionary, `x` is now a thunk. Now no dictionary needs to be applied to evaluate `y`! `y` is just the application of the pair constructor to two pointers to the `x` thunk. Applying a constructor doesn't count as computation, so it's never delayed lazily.